# Why would a .NET app stop being able to perform any network I/O?

Tags: .net, winsock

I'm investigating a problem seen on a client workstation where a, fairly large, WinForms .NET 3.5 application will occasionally stop being able to perform any type of network operation and will eventually freeze due to a network operation being performed on the main thread.

By network operation, I mean anything that requires a new network connection. The application  connects to multiple Oracle databases and SOAP web services.

Inspecting a memory dump of the application shows various blocked calls to unmanaged code on different threads:

DNS lookup stuck (`System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods+SafeNetHandlesXPOrLater.getaddrinfo`)

Open Sockets stuck (`System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods+OSSOCK.WSAConnect`)

Close Sockets stuck (`System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods+SafeNetHandles.closesocket`)

Open ODBC stuck (`System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.SQLDriverConnectW`)

The top of the unmanaged stacks for all of the above look like this:

```
0a90df4c 77858cd8 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15
0a90df74 73c5716f ntdll!RtlIntegerToUnicodeString+0x20b
0a90dfbc 76f45db1 siifslsp!WSPStartup+0x483f
```

After restarting the application, it returns to normal. This suggests to me some type of resource leak, but how can I track this down?

I checked for instances of open network connections and can see the following counts:

- `System.Net.HttpWebRequest` 5 instances
- `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` 11 instances
- `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle` 4 instances

These don't look unusually high to me.

**Update 1** - Truncated Output of `!FinalizeQueue`

Output of `!FinalizeQueue` doesn't show anything unusual to me. I've limited it to anything IO related.

```
0:024> !FinalizeQueue
SyncBlocks to be cleaned up: 0
MTA Interfaces to be released: 0
STA Interfaces to be released: 0
----------------------------------
generation 0 has 359 finalizable objects (41f35654->41f35bf0)
generation 1 has 0 finalizable objects (41f35654->41f35654)
generation 2 has 10697 finalizable objects (41f2af30->41f35654)
Ready for finalization 0 objects (41f35bf0->41f35bf0)
Statistics:
      MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
6e612a38        1           20 System.Net.SafeLocalFree
6ea7e550        1           24 System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
6a606c54        1           24 System.Data.Odbc.OdbcEnvironmentHandle
6e60f7f4        2           40 System.Net.SafeFreeAddrInfo
05da845c        2           40 System.Net.SafeCloseSocket+InnerSafeCloseSocket
0642c010        2           56 System.Net.SafeCloseSocketAndEvent
6e6106bc        4           96 System.Net.SafeRegistryHandle
6e6105d0        4          112 System.Net.SafeCloseSocketAndEvent
6a6069bc        4          112 System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnectionHandle
6a6060c8        4          256 System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
6e60f764       11          264 System.Net.SafeCloseSocket
6e6115cc        7          336 System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream
66e60eeec       11          836 System.Net.Sockets.Socket

Total 11056 objects
```

**Update 2** - Using `!locks` and `!critsec` to see where the blocks are

The output of `!critsec` is:

```
0:002> !critsec 73c7147c

CritSec siifslsp!GetLspGuid+1a0fc at 73c7147c
WaiterWoken        No
LockCount          8
RecursionCount     1
OwningThread       5f24
EntryCount         0
ContentionCount    8
*** Locked
```

Not sure what the `5f24` refers to. The output of `!Threads` doesn't show any threads with an `OSID` of `5f24`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I admit I don't have a clear answer, but here's some suggestions.

First, try to work out what the threads are blocking on by using the `!waitlist` command in WinDbg as explained in [this blog post](http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/06/22/blocked-finalizer-thread/). This might throw a clue which could explain why different threads are blocking.

[Here's another handy blog post](http://voneinem-windbg.blogspot.co.uk/2006/04/how-to-find-out-on-which-thread.html) which explains how to dig deeper to find what is blocking a thread.

Another source of good information might be the `Event Viewer`, specifically `the Windows Logs -> System` section. You could scan the entries here and look for any `Error` or `Warnings` and see what they say. There could be network related messages being posted there, you never know.

I will keep updating this answer as I find other potentially useful information for you.

Comment: The siifslsp was a WinSock LSP associated with an uninstalled application. Removing the WinSock LSP resolved the problem.

Comment: @Iain Glad you solved the problem. Did my answer help you out, I wasn't sure what a WinSock LSP is and how you found out it was associated with an uninstalled application. Sounds very deep :)

Comment: It's a long story but your answer inspired me to dig deeper into the unmanaged code. From Update 2 in my answer I used the command `lmv m siifslsp` to identify the `siifslsp` DLL and some googling told me that the 'GetLspGuid' method was something you find on a WinSock LSP.  I got the DLL and opened it up in Notepad to search for any strings that might hint to it's origin. I found the Vendor and eventually  tracked down the Software that it was part of, the user recognised the software as something that he had removed from his machine recently as it was causing him problems. Case closed.

Comment: I don't really know the details about LSPs but I recalled years ago encountering problems on machines where a corrupt WinSock stack would stop networking from happening. Usually because an application had inserted it's own unreliable plugin (LSP?) into the WinSock stack

Answer (score 0):

.NET will limit the number of remote connections to 2 by default.

Make sure the following property is appropriately set:

```
<system.net>
  <connectionManagement>
    <add address = "*" maxconnection = "24" />
  </connectionManagement>
</system.net>
```

Look at the following MSDN page for further information:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.configuration.connectionmanagementelement.maxconnection(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.net.configuration.connectionmanagementelement.maxconnection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)